# Can't update mysql table with $id

Tags: php, mysql, content-management-system, get, sql-update

I'm trying to make an edit function to edit products, 
like a small CMS.

The problem is that i can't update my mysql table 
with $id = $_GET['id']; and then $query = "UPDATE producten SET naam='$naam' WHERE id='$id'";
i've searched the whole internet but couldn't find anything that helped.

When i try $id = '50'; for instance i't does update the product with the id of 50.

And if i try $id = $_GET['id']; echo $id; i do get the right id.

Here is my full code:

```
        <?php           
        include "../php_includes/config.php";

        //Conect to the server/database
        if($connect){
            $errors = array();

        // check if the 'id' variable is set in URL, and check that it is valid
        if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']))
        {
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        }
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM producten WHERE id='$id'");
        while($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
                $naam_oud = $query_row['naam'];
                $naam_de_oud = $query_row['naam_de'];
                $prijs_oud = $query_row['prijs'];
                $image_oud = $query_row['image'];
        }
        //Display Posts
        if(isset($_POST['naam'],$_POST['naam_de'], $_POST['prijs'])){
            $naam = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['naam']));
            $naam_de = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['naam_de']));
            $prijs = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['prijs']));
            $image = $_FILES['file']['name'];
            $tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

            if($image){
                $location = "product_foto/.$image";
                move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$location);

            }else{
                $location = $image_oud;
            }
    //Errors
            if(empty($naam)){
                $errors[] = '<p class="error">Vul een nederlandse product naam in.</p>';
            }
            if(empty($naam_de)){
                $errors[] = '<p class="error">Vul een duitse product naam in.</p>';
            }

            if(empty($prijs)){
                $errors[] = '<p class="error">Vul een prijs in</p>';
            }
    //Insert Into Database
            if (empty($errors)){
                $query = "UPDATE producten SET naam='$naam',naam_de='$naam_de',prijs='$prijs', image='$location' WHERE id='$id'";
                    if (mysql_query($query)){
                        header('Location: ../admin/admin.php');die();               
                    } else{
                        $errors[] = '<p class="error">Oeps.. Er is iets verkeerd gegaan. Probeer later opnieuw.</p>';
                    }
    //Errors
            } else{
                foreach($errors as $error){
                echo $error;
                }
            }
        }
        }else{ 
            echo'<p class="error">Kan geen verbinding maken.<br/> Probeer later opnieuw.</p>';
        }
    ?>


            <form class="margin" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>" method="POST" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
                <strong>Product naam Nederlands</strong> <br/>  <input value="<?php echo $naam_oud;?> " id="focus" type="text" class="input_field" name="naam" maxlength="150" style="width:600px;"><br/><br/>
                <strong>Product naam Duits</strong> <br/>  <input id="focus" type="text" class="input_field" value="<?php echo $naam_de_oud;?>"name="naam_de" maxlength="150" style="width:600px;"><br/><br/>
                <strong> Prijs</strong> <br/> <input id="focus" type="text" class="input_field" name="prijs" value="<?php echo $prijs_oud;?> "maxlength="150" style="width:600px;"><br/>
                Vorm: euros,centen. zonder euro tekens. (Toevoegingen kunnen na het bedrag geplaatst worden.)<br/><br/>
                <strong> Foto</strong> <br/><input type="file" name="file"/><br/><br/>
                <br/><input type="submit" class="button" value="Bewerken" id="submit"/><a href="../admin/admin">Annuleren</a>
            </form>
```

Comment: I would add a `var_dump($query)` just before the mysql_query and see what's the full statement that comes out. If the statement is correct, you can try running it manually against the database and see if it does what you expect.

Comment: When you say you can't update, what's the error you're seeing?

Comment: Where is $_GET['id'] coming from? can you show that code please?

Comment: No, there are no errors. it follows my header, without changing the table

Comment: the id comes from: echo '<a href="../php_includes/edit_producten.php?id=' . $query_row['id'] . '" " >Edit</a>';

Comment: i used the var_dump($query) and this is my output: string 'UPDATE producten SET naam='pvc schort volledige lengte 2',naam_de='test',prijs='45,00 ', image='' WHERE id=''' (length=109)

Answer (score 0):

```
    // check if the 'id' variable is set in URL, and check that it is valid
    if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']))
    {
        $id = $_GET['id'];
    }
```

Did you verify that this if statement is true and $id is really set?

Comment: Apparently, he did. "And if i try $id = $_GET['id']; echo $id; i do get the right id.".

Comment: I wasn't able to confirm that he tested this in his if statement :)

Comment: I would add $id=intval($_GET['id']) to prevent SQL injection

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`"UPDATE producten SET naam='".$naam."', naam_de='".$naam_de."', prijs='".$prijs."', image='".$location."' WHERE id='".$id."'";`